# How does DNS domain verification work?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, web, dns

Im reading [this google doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en) on how to hook up app engine to a custom domain (a domain I purchased through a different registrar)

I get to a point where I have to "Supply the domain name ("example.com") and click Verify. This opens up a new tab titled Webmaster Central." and walk through some prompts to prove I own the domain.

After doing this "domain verification is automatically re-confirmed about every 30 days".

What exactly is "domain verification"? Is there like a domain verification protocol that all DNS registrars must support? What communication is happening between google and say godady or AWS (route53)? Is there a special type of DNS record specifically for verification?

I don't understand whats actually happening to prove I own the domain and if this process is standardized or each DNS provider has their own solution/quirks for doing this.

Comment: TXT records. Related: https://support.google.com/quickfixes/answer/6252336?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179) (also accessible via the Webmaster Central help menu):

> What is verification?
>
> Verification is the process of proving that you own the site or app
>   that you claim to own. We need to confirm ownership because once you
>   are verified for a site or app you have access to its private Google
>   Search data, and can affect how Google Search crawls it.

No, it's not a standard. Each hosting provider asking for it had their own method/algorithm of doing it.

Google actually has several such optional methods so that you can choose one that best works for your case. They're listed in the `Verification methods` chapter further down in the above-mentioned doc, together with some explanation of how each of them operates. Not all of them are based on DNS registrar actions.

Also keep in mind that Webmaster Central is used for other sites as well, not only for GAE-based sites - just in case some things might not make sense in a GAE context. This includes sites not even hosted on/using Google infrastructure/services.